# TP-Link T4U v3 AC1300 - Kubuntu 19.10 - Driver not working

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, kubuntu

**Goal:** to get TP-Link T4U v3 AC1300 working with Kubuntu 19.10 (Kernel 5.3.0-23-generic).

**Status:** Unsolved

The official driver did not compile on Kubuntu 19.10 (Kernel 5.3.0-23-generic) nor did this version (https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8822bu) which appears to work for some older versions of Ubuntu.

So I tried https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu. I was able to find networks but unable to connect.

```
$ dkms status
rtl88x2bu, 5.6.1, 5.3.0-23-generic, x86_64: installed

$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 2357:0115 TP-Link 802.11ac NIC
```

Comment: Does /var/log/syslog give any clue as to errors during the connect process? Is wpasupplicant installed? (`dpkg -l wpa* | grep ii`)

Answer (score 0):

TP-Link T4U works fine with driver from [here](https://github.com/EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu).

Tested on Ubuntu 19.10 and 20.04.